# Loop in Imacros using Javascript

Tags: javascript, imacros

how can i loop imm(imacros) script with javascript

I searched a little bit and found this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
iimPlay(marconame.iim);
}
```

but when i use it my browser(Firefox 18) hangs :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
iimPlay("macroname.iim");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is this option too.

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:some_class"


var n=10;


for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
{
iimPlay(macro)
}
```

In codes above n is not defined so it will return an error.