# iMacros: How to handle missing elements/value for extracting data properly

Tags: attributes, element, extract, imacros

I have this code...

```
VERSION BUILD=8032216
TAB T=1
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO={{URL}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR0 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:vs_members_companyname* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:member-address* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR2 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:vs_members_contact* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR3 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:vs_members_phone* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR4 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:vs_members_email* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR5 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:vs_members_url* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR6 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
SET !EXTRACT NULL
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR0}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR2}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR3}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR4}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR5}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR6}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=AdelcookChamber.csv
SET !EXTRACT NULL
```

When iMacros doesn't find the text/element/ for the attribute class on the page it gives result #EANF# . However it moves my extracted .csv file columns around and leaves the #EANF# at the end of the extracted data in which those elements are found on page, it's actually the ones above the data to be extracted on page that don't have these elements/values.

I'm running this in iMacros browser edition with a play loop set at 8. Anyway to handle this without getting into scripting? I need for it to just mark #EANF# for attribute values that can't be found on page.
**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**IceD** thanks bro for the reply! Can you help me out, since I don't know JavaScript? How would this code look base on my code here?

I cleaned the code up so you can see that it pulls everything fine; except the email(s) and web address(es) when it doesn't find the elements it mis-places into other rows.

I'm playing a loop 8X (number of records on page).

```
VERSION BUILD=8032216
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
FILTER TYPE=IMAGES STATUS=ON

URL GOTO=http://www.adelcookchamber.org/membership-directory/category/advertising/
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:vs_members_companyname EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:member-address EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:vs_members_contact EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:vs_members_phone EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:vs_members_email EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:vs_members_url EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:vs_members_cats EXTRACT=TXT

Wait SECONDS=2
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Adelcook_Chamber.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in JavaScript and assign extracted value to a variable. 
Use iimGetLastExtract() for that purpose. Each time you have value `#EANF#` delete it or change it in some ways.

Comment: IceD check-out my reply above; just below -------

Comment: Search on stack overflow. :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909553/loop-in-imacros-using-javascript