# How to loop only a series of steps in iMacros

Tags: loops, imacros

I have a 10 step iMacro script that is set to loop 500 times via the Play (Loop) button.

The thing is, I only want steps 5-10 looped. The partial goal is to avoid the "*URL GOTO=*" step.

Thank you for your time.

Here's what it looks like:

```
VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 20
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*13 + 6); randomNumber;")
TAB T=1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=VALUE:value
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:text
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
```

I want to loop only the last 3 steps of the script.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909553/loop-in-imacros-using-javascript

You can apply this.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I'm still not understanding that.

Answer (score 4):

In `*.iim` file you can't loop specific lines from code, use `*.js` file instead:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*13 + 6);  
var macro = "CODE:SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";  
macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 20" + "\n";    
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=VALUE:value" + "\n";    
macro += "TAG POS=R1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:text" + "\n";    
macro += "WAIT SECONDS={{rand}}";    
for(var i=0;i<500;i++)    
{
iimDisplay(i);    
iimSet("i", i);    
iimSet("rand", rand);    
iimPlay(macro);}
```

Save this code in a *.js file and hit the Play button (not the one with loop).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget use add your macro here :

```
iimPlay(macro);}
```

Change macro with your macro name, and use "" mark.. example :

```
"testmacro"
```