# IF Statements and Conditions for iMacros Firefox

Tags: firefox, if-statement, macros, firefox-addon, imacros

So I'm trying to make a macro to catch Pokemon from maps in this game but there if you encounter a Turf War it will show this image:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/W6Tjd8l.jpg]

As you can see the click button says "Lets Battle!" and it redirects you to a battle link.

However, I want to make an `if` statement that if I encounter this battle link I would refresh the page instead and let me go here.

Does anybody know how to code `if` statements for this?

So here's how I want it to work:

```
if (it encounters the Turf Battle)
   will click another link
else
   keep clicking the map to catch using the click x and y
```

EDIT: I tried this syntax:

```
if (TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:You<SP>Don't<SP>Belong<SP>Here!)
{ 
    REFRESH
}
```

but it won't work. Any help maybe?
Giving me this error:

```
SyntaxError: unknown command: IF, line: 1 (Error code: -910)
```

Comment: There is no IF statement in imacros - you need to create javascript or similar script to use If statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909553/loop-in-imacros-using-javascript   <<<< and here you have an example of how to make if statement using JS scripting.

Comment: @Bestmacros How do you create a Javascript or similar script to do that? Do you just create another macro?

Comment: @IceD So basically what I have to do is code the original map catching macro right? But which macro do I run to start this whole macroing loop? The one with the IF statement or the one with the original script? Sorry if I'm a little new to this.

Comment: you need to rebuild your original macro in javascript format.

Comment: And search some more on stackoverflow for iMacros javascript solutions. There are tons of answered questions. Check bestmacros profile and my profile. There are examples there in answers which you can use.

Comment: @Bestmacros How do I rebuild that? Do you have any advice on it?

Comment: Ok so I tried this syntax but it won't work (Check edited post)

Comment: Delete your dupes please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by *.js file (not *.iim file) :

1. open notepad
2. copy my code
3. edit `YOUR-URL` to your url
4. save this to `your-file.js` ( `path= imacro path` )
5. open firefox & run `your-file.js`

good luck

CODE:

```
       iimPlay("Code:URL GOTO=YOUR-URL")
   var macro;                        
    macro+="SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST\n";
    macro+="TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT\n";
    iimPlay(macro_var);
    var result=iimGetLastExtract();
    if(result=="You<SP>Don't<SP>Belong<SP>Here!")
    {
    iimDisplay("success");
    REFRESH
    }
```