# IF ERROR statement in iMacros

Tags: if-statement, imacros

could anyone please help me with this? Does anybody have an idea how to make Line 17 to a working code in iMacros for Firefox? I have no clue.

Many thanks!

```
VERSION BUILD=8510617 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !FOLDER_DATASOURCE C:\Users\XXX\Documents\iMacros\Macros\
SET !DATASOURCE Ticker-Symbols_2.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=http://de.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=YHOO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/q/hp ATTR=ID:pageTicker CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/q/hp ATTR=*
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\Users\XXX\Documents\iMacros\Macros\Ergebnisse\ FILE={{!COL1}}_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd}}.csv WAIT=YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=STRONG ATTR=TXT:Aufbereitet<SP>für<SP>Tabellenkalkulationsprogramm


IF Error occurs write {{!COL1}} into a new line in file XYZ


SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 3
```

Comment: there is no IF statement in imacros - you need to use javascript or similar

Comment: You have to use javascript scripting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909553/loop-in-imacros-using-javascript