# Insert a few lines of Javascript in my IMacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I got 3 questions wich all have to do with the javascript in IMacros.

First I want an if statement like " if you see this text: You succesfully stole a car"
then select the last checkbox and go on with the rest of the imacros script.
If not then just go on with the imacros script.

So the 3 questions are:
How do I insert Javascript in imacros?
How do I make an if statement with text and if not then just dont do anything?
How can javascript always select the last checkbox on the site.

here is my imacros script:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Auto<SP>Burglary
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=ID:selectedCrime[2]
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=*
Now here needs the if statement need to come and the select last checkbox
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=ID:goState         CONTENT=%Pennsylvania-0
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=7 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/autoburglary.php ATTR=*
```

Thnx anyway!

Answer (score 1):

In this question bellow you have an example of how to make JavaScript macro.

[Loop in Imacros using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909553/loop-in-imacros-using-javascript)

Also you can add CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER and to the end of iMacros code. That way the script will just hover over a page element.

The last question you asked needs more work. You will have to do it yourself since from what you told us I can't do anything.

But here is an idea. Try to search with CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER for checkboxes from position one to last one. When iMacros returns error "remember" that position, decrement it and use it to click on it. With a little work you can manage it.

Comment: thanks for ur comment i didnt find the time to work it all out but its fixed