# imacros, looping through dates

Tags: loops, imacros

I'm trying to write a macro that will:

go to a specific website 
type a symbol in the useform
click on a drop down menu to select a date next to the symbol
click on a button to request the data
go back to the original page and click on the next date

I want to loop this until I have gotten all of the dates. Here is part of my code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=ID:ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wDates CONTENT=%265.txt4
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=ID:ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:aspnetForm ATTR=ID:ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSendData
BACK
BACK
```

I believe I have to make changes to where it says CONTENT=%265.txt4 but I'm just not sure how to change this.

Comment: Use search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909553/loop-in-imacros-using-javascript