# iMacro how to show an error if Select Content does not match

Tags: show

**Hello I am using iMacro for Firefox to select a specific option from a dropdown box


This is the code I am using:**

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:DataFeedForm ATTR=ID:c2 CONTENT=%30
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\06.<SP>CSV<SP>ConvertioN\Temp FILE=Australia.csv WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:c7
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:DataFeedForm ATTR=ID:c2 CONTENT=%31
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\06.<SP>CSV<SP>ConvertioN\Temp FILE=Austria.csv WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:c7
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:DataFeedForm ATTR=ID:c2 CONTENT=%37
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\06.<SP>CSV<SP>ConvertioN\Temp FILE=Belarus.csv WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:c7
```

**Now the problem is that if the Content=%30 does not match the macro continues running, I dont want that. I want the macro to stop immediately if the content does not match.**

**I have also try to change the first line, is working but the problem still remains:**

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:DataFeedForm ATTR=ID:c2 CONTENT=$Australia
```

**_________________Read bellow, I found the Solution without javascript._________________**

Comment: This was asked so many times. Use javascript scripting. >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909553/loop-in-imacros-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Once again I found the Solution my own.**

**For a few months now, I have done more than 5 questions and no one answers me. I will probably have to pay subscription to other sites because this site does not help anything.**

**Only wiseacres, occurring without any sense and they tell the familiar poem, this question has already been done.**

So I inform the friend who respond, that I do not need java script in imacro to do what I want. The solution was very simple, **he needed only two asterisks**.

***So BEFORE:***

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:DataFeedForm ATTR=ID:c2 CONTENT=$Australia
```

***And AFTER:***

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:DataFeedForm ATTR=ID:c2 CONTENT=$*Australia*
```

If the content does not match, the imacro stops and displays an error message.
This is What I wanted from the beginning.

Thanks to my self. chears...

Comment: Don't give up on stack overflow. There are a lot of answers on stack about iMacros. You just have to search. 
Besides, looking and finding solutions on your own is the best. I just saw this question for the first time. I don't know why I haven't seen it before. Keep asking questions and you will get a reply. 
The mistake you made was you haven't placed tags or wrote iMacros.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your time. I just spend too many hours to solve my problems and sometimes my nerves reach their limits.

Comment: After some time you will need less and less time. Take care.