# Using if statement in iMacros for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, if-statement, automation, imacros

I want to automate a website which only supports Internet explorer. To automate the website i have to use if statement i read the documentation of iMacros which says iMacros do not support if statement but we can do it by using javascript(or any other scripting language). But the javascript supports in iMacros for Firefox not for Internet Explorer.

I have to check weather a particular text is present on website if present then do something, If not present then do something else.

Is there any other way to use if statement in Imacros for Internet Explorer. Please help ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909553/loop-in-imacros-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks for answer...But i want to use in IE. I am using following codes

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
iimPlay("FillForm.iim");
}

But its giving 

Error -1100: Unknown command: FOR at line: 3

Any suggestion...

Comment: -1100 Load Failed: Failed to load the macro (syntax or I/O error) (Found wrong macro command while loading file).

http://wiki.imacros.net/Error_and_Return_Codes

Comment: If i am using same code in firefox its working fine but when i am trying to run in internet explorer it does not work. Do you have any working code for internet explorer where if statement has been used. If you have please provide me. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about IE and does it run in JavaScript but Imacros browser is free, can use JS and it's based on IE.

Comment: I searched on google a lot but i did not find any relevant answer even when we install imacros in Internet explorer in demo file it does not show any macro related to javascript for internet explorer.

Comment: Download iMacros Browser here >>> http://imacros.net/download 
It's based on IE so it can work for you. And it supports JS.